# Any good resources for using DRF api with Vanilla Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have a project for which I have made all the relevant REST APIs using DRF. I however have to implement them on the frontend which has to be made using Django templates and hitting the APIs using requests module.

Is there a good resource where I can reference into this, as I can't find anything on it online.

Comment: If you replace 'vanilla django' with 'vanilla js' you would have much better chances with finding a good tutorial. :)

Comment: @alv2017 I know, but that is the requirement.